Find $f'(x)$ given $\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^3+1} \frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)} \,dt= \frac1x$
Question:
Find $f'(x)$ given that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^3+1} \frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)} \,dt= \frac1x$$
My approach:
If I integrate, I will get $\frac d {dx}(F(x^3+1)-F(1)) = \frac1x$ which is equal to $f(x^3+1)\cdot3x^2-f(1)\cdot0=3x^2f(x^3+1)=\frac1x$
$f(x^3+1)=\frac1{3x^3}\implies f(x^3)=\frac1{3(x-1)^3}\implies f(x)=\frac1{3(x-1)}\implies f(x)=\frac1{3x-3}\implies f'(x)=-\frac3{(3x-3)^2}$ QED.
Motivation about why I am trying to solve this question: 
I watched a bprp video on youtube, title: "finding the derivative from an integral equation".
And at timestamp 05:12, this question is introduced. So I tried to solve this question and I want to know if I got it right. Please forgive me, if I am doing something obviously wrong that I don't realise, I will try to correct it.
YouTube video link:
https://youtu.be/5OsohvNAKhY?t=312

What I googled before I posted this:

https://www.cuemath.com/calculus/derivative-of-an-integral/
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5BIntegrate%5Bf%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5BIntegrate%5Bf%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C1%2CPower%5Bx%2C3%5D%2B1%7D%5D%2Cx%5D
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5BIntegrate%5BDivide%5Bf%27%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%2C1%2Bf%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bt%2C1%2CPower%5Bx%2C3%5D%2B1%7D%5D%3DDivide%5B1%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%5C%2844%29+solve+f%27%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29

Note: I am not always quick to respond, so give me time whenever I try to understand a step or edit.
Major Edit -> My second approach:
For my sanity, I wrote (typed) everything down what my steps right now are. This includes your comments and answers, because I want to know if I am doing right and that I am not missing something, there is still a chance that I am doing something wrong. And also, thank you for your patience in advanced, if you are reading/commenting/answering my question.
If $$
F(x)=\int_1^{x^3+1}\frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}dt$$
then,
$$
\begin{equation}
F(x)=\ln|1+f(t)|\big|_1^{x^3+1}=\ln|1+f(x^3+1)|-\ln|1+f(1)|
\end{equation}
$$
Extra: ln(a)-ln(b)=ln(a/b):
$$
=\ln\left|\frac{1+f(x^3+1)}{1+f(1)}\right|
$$
Ofcourse the extra is not necessary, and it will only complicate things more if we try to differentiate using chain and quotient rule.
Differentiation:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac d{dx}F(x)&=\frac d{dx}\left(\ln|1+f(x^3+1)|-\ln|1+f(1)|\right)\\&=\frac{1}{1+f(x^3+1)}\cdot f'(x^3+1)\cdot3x^2-\frac{1}{1+f(1)}\cdot f'(1)\cdot0\\
&=3x^2\cdot\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}=\frac1x
\end{align}$$
Integrate both sides:
$$
\begin{align}
\int{3x^2\cdot\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}}dx&=\int{\frac1x}dx
\end{align}
$$
Using u-substitution:
If $u=x^3+1$, then $du=3x^2dx$
$$
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{f'(u)}{1+f(u)}}du&=\ln|x|\\
\ln|1+f(u)|&=\ln|1+f(x^3+1)|\\
\implies 1+f(x^3+1)&=x\\
\implies f(x^3+1)&=x-1\\
\implies f(x^3)&=(x-1)-1\\
\implies f(x^3)&=x-2\\
\implies f(x)&=x^{1/3}-2\\
\implies f'(x)&=\frac1{3}x^{-2/3}\\
\implies f'(x)&=\frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}
\end{align}
$$
QED.
Note: I ignored the absolute values for now at the differentiation step (at d/dx F(x)), so that could be improved.

I think you have a problem with $\frac{d}{dx} F(x^3 + 1)$. Notice that $F(x) = \int \frac{f'(t)dt}{1+f(t)}$

is this better?
$$\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}-\frac{f'(1)}{1+f(1)}=\frac1x$$
I will check your F(x) @openspace, to see where this leads me.

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^3+1} \frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)} ,dt=3x^2\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}$

I will comment on your second solution. The first one has several errors as well, but since you provided a second attempt I assume that's the one you want the focus to be on. I will also show later that there are no solutions to the problem, as there are no $f$ satisfying the given relation.
My first comment is not really a mathematical error, but it's something you could save some time on in the future. In particular when you compute
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\ln\lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert-\ln\lvert1+f(1)\rvert\right)=\frac{1}{1+f(x^3+1)}\cdot f'(x^3+1)\cdot3x^2-\frac{1}{1+f(1)}\cdot f'(1)\cdot0,$$
the second term is unnecessarily complicated: you can just say immediately that $\ln\lvert1+f(1)\rvert$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$, and if you do so you avoid for example using the chain rule twice as you did, and it is more generally applicable.
Now on to where the math itself starts to break apart. My first comment is that when you write
$$\int\frac{f'(u)}{1+f(u)}\,\mathrm du=\ln\lvert x\rvert,$$
you are missing a constant on the right-hand side. When you do indefinite integration, this is important to include. So it should read something along the lines of
$$\int\frac{f'(u)}{1+f(u)}\,\mathrm du=\ln\lvert x\rvert+C.$$
The next issue is when you claim that
$$\ln\lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert\implies 1+f(x^3+1)=x.$$
This is also not immediately true. What you do have is that
$$\ln\lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert\implies \lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert=\lvert x\rvert.$$
In particular you can only conclude that
$$1+f(x^3+1)=\pm x,$$
and it does not necessarily have to be the same sign in the $\pm$ everywhere: it could be that you have $1+f(x^3+1)=x$ for $x>0$ but $1+f(x^3+1)=-x<0$. You need to address this.
The next error is the implication
$$f(x^3+1)=x-1\implies f(x^3)=(x-1)-1.$$
In the left-hand side you have replaced $x^3+1$ with $x^3$, but in the right-hand side you have replaced $x$ with $x-1$. But $x^3\neq(x-1)^3+1$ in general, so this is not a correct operation. We can even see it breaking apart if we plug in, for example, $x=2$. Then the first equality tells us that
$$f(9)=f(2^3+1)=2-1=1,$$
but from the second one, if we plug in $x=\sqrt[3]{9}$, we find that
$$f(9)=f(\sqrt[3]{9}^3)=\sqrt[3]{9}-2.$$
But $1\neq\sqrt[3]{9}-2$. The correct thing to do here instead would be to either replace $x$ with $(x^3-1)^{1/3}$ if you wanted $f(x^3)$, or replace $x$ with $(x-1)^{1/3}$ if you wanted $f(x)$ right away. This would give you that
$$f(x)=f(((x-1)^{1/3})^3+1)=((x-1)^{1/3})-1-1=(x-1)^{1/3}-2.$$

Let's now take the above into consideration and solve the problem using a similar method to the one you tried, but instead done correctly.
We start with the equation
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_1^{x^3+1}\frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{x}.$$
If we integrate both sides we obtain that
$$\int_1^{x^3+1}\frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}\,\mathrm dt=\ln\lvert x\rvert+C$$
for some constant $C\in\mathbb R$. By substituting
$$u=1+f(t),\quad\mathrm du=f'(t)\,\mathrm dt,$$
we can furthermore compute
$$\int_1^{x^3+1}\frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}\,\mathrm dt=\int_{1+f(1)}^{1+f(x^3+1)}\frac{\mathrm du}{u}=\ln\lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert-\ln\lvert 1+f(1)\rvert.$$
Taking $D=C+\ln\lvert 1+f(1)\rvert$ we get then that
$$\ln\lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert+D,$$
and so
$$\lvert 1+f(x^3+1)\rvert=e^{\ln\lvert x\rvert+D}=e^D\lvert x\rvert=E\lvert x\rvert,$$
where $E=e^D$. This implies that
$$1+f(x^3+1)=\pm Ex,$$
where the sign $\pm$ is constant for $x\in(-\infty,0)$, $x\in(0,1)$, $x\in(1,\infty)$, but could potentially change between them (this is due to continuity and the fact that I do not assume that $f$ is even defined at $1$). This gives us that
$$f(x^3+1)=\pm Ex-1,$$
and so
$$f(x)=f(((x-1)^{1/3})^3+1)=\pm E(x-1)^{1/3}-1.$$
Differentiating we then get the final answer as
$$f'(x)=\pm\frac{E}{3(x-1)^{2/3}}.$$
I claim now that no such $f$ gives a solution! Fix an $f$ with
$$f(x)=\pm E(x-1)^{1/3}-1$$
and the sign of $\pm$ determined as above. Then
$$f'(x)=\pm\frac{E}{3(x-1)^{2/3}},$$
so
$$\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)}=\frac{1}{3(x-1)}.$$
Consequently
$$\int_1^{x^3+1}\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)}\,\mathrm dx=\int_1^{x^3+1}\frac{\mathrm dx}{3(x-1)}=\biggl[\frac{1}{3}\ln\lvert x-1\rvert\biggr]_1^{x^3+1}=\infty,$$
as $\ln\xi\to-\infty$ as $\xi\downarrow0$.
We have thus shown that if there was an $f$ satisfying the above relation, then it would be of the above form. But no $f$ of the above form can satisfy the above relation.
There as thus no $f$ satisfying the given relation!

Let $$A(t)=\int \frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}dt$$
Substitute $y=f(t)$ $\implies dy=f'(t) dt$ $$\implies A(t)=\int \frac{1}{1+y}dy$$
$$\implies A(t)=\ln(1+y)$$
$$\implies A(t)=\ln(1+f(t))$$
Let $$B(x)=\int_1^{x^3+1} \frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}dt$$
$$\implies B(x)=\ln(1+f(x^3+1))-\ln(1+f(1))$$
Let $$C(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_1^{x^3+1} \frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)} \,dt\right)$$ $$\implies C(x)=\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}3x^2$$
Now according to the question $$C(x)=\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}3x^2=\frac{1}{x}$$
Integrate both sides, $$\int\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}3x^2dx=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$ $$\implies \int\frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}d(x^3+1)=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$ $$\implies \ln(1+f(x^3+1))=\ln(x)$$ $$\implies x=1+f(x^3+1)$$ Here we ignore the constants.
Replace $x$ by $(w-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, and we get $$(w-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1=f(w)$$ $$\implies (x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1=f(x)$$
Now you can easily find $f'(x)$ $$\boxed{f'(x)=\frac{1}{3(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}$$

I might be not reading it correctly, but at the step $C(x)=\frac{d}{dx}...=$, should one not apply the chain rule, multiplying by a factor of $3x^2$?

@J.D i corrected it

Btw, just as an aside for the answer, it is not wrong, but one could observe that you can reach the conclusion '$3x^2 \cdot \frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)}= \frac{1}{x}$' by the fundamental theorem of calculus; you do not actually have to find the primitive to apply this result.

@J.D Ohh i see... actually I forget all theorems real quick so I need to start from the basic

I didn't downvote ! It's a good answer.

@J.D oh damn...we can directly reach that result by the lebnitz rule I guess (i apologise if the spelling is wrong)...how can I forget this

I guess it's the Newton Lebnitz formula

Yes it's that one , with a vanishing partial derivative term.

If $G(x)=\int_1^x\frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)} , dt$, then $B'(x)=C(x)=\frac{d}{dx} G(x^3+1)=G'(x^3+1)3x^2= \frac{f'(x^3+1)}{1+f(x^3+1)} 3x^2$ by chain rule + ftc. You could also use sub $y=1+f(x^3+1)$.

This is new to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
If you have an answer using this method, than you will make me happy :D
Because I will learn something new. Ofcourse, I will try to use the Leibniz integral rule too.

For your $f$ you get that $\frac{f'(t)}{1+f(t)}=\frac{1}{3(t-1)}$, which is not integrable from $1$ to $x^3+1$. There are in fact no $f$ satisfying the given relation

@Lorago damn bro...I am getting $\ln(0)$ after putting the limits...there is some discrepancy in my solution...thanks for pointing that out
